# type и interface node-telegram-bot-api (применить)

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, typescript, typescript-типы

плохо разбираюсь в интерфейсах и типах (не могу применить их у сторонней библиотеки node-telegram-bot-api)
Как сделать вот это в typescript
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при разработке typescript ругается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    let options= {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard:[
            [{text: '1', callback_data: 'asads'}]
        ]
    })
}
return  bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Отгадывай', options);
```

в настройка typescript установлено     "skipLibCheck": true,

Попробовал вот это решение, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977699/telegram-bot-inline-keyboard-via-node-js

```
bot.onText(/^\/start$/, function (msg) {
const opts = {
    reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
    reply_markup: {
        resize_keyboard: true,
        one_time_keyboard: true,
        keyboard: [
          [{text: 'Level 1'}],
        ],
    }
};

bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "I'm a test robot", opts);
```

});

не пойму почему кнопка под меню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, вам надо установить [типы для вашей библиотеки](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40types/node-telegram-bot-api) и использовать их

Comment: Установил, не помогает, вроде тут решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977699/telegram-bot-inline-keyboard-via-node-js

Comment: После этого получается, но вот только кнопка в низу

Comment: Не стоит в одном посте размещат 2 не связанные между собой ошибки. Вопрос был про типы, а тут теперь положение кнопки всплыло... Оформите новый вопрос про расположение кнопки, если с типизацией у вас проблема решилась, если нет, добавьте ваш код после установки типов и типизации ваших переменных

Answer (score 0):

```
   const opts = {
    reply_markup: {
        resize_keyboard: true,
        inline_keyboard: [
            [{ text: "Случайно", callback_data: "random" }],
            [{ text: "Спорт", callback_data: "sport" }],
            [{ text: "Кино", callback_data: "cinema" }],
            [{ text: "Музыка", callback_data: "music" }],
        ],
    },
}
return  bot.sendMessage(chatId,  "fdgf", opts);
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: {
            resize_keyboard: true,
            one_time_keyboard: true,
            keyboard: [
                [{text: 'Случайно'}, {text: 'Спорт'}],
                [{text: 'Кино'}],
                [{text: 'Музыка'}],
                [{text: '❌ Закрыть меню'}]
            ],
        }
    }
 return  bot.sendMessage(chatId,  "fdgf", opts);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]